# validate.js for datepicker not working on selecting date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-validate

I am trying to create validation rules using validate.js for date-time picker but validation is not working when I am selecting date from the calendar.
It is working when I am manually entering date and time.

Please assist me.

Comment: You need to programmatically trigger validation when the picker is closed.  See the answer below.  In the future, please search this site for answers before posting... and if you post a question, please always follow the guidelines and include the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="jQueryValidateTest">
    <input type="date" required>
</form>

$(function() {

  $( "#jQueryValidateTest" ).validate();

  $( "[type=date]" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
      $( this ).valid();
    }
  });
});
```